# Merging Overlapping Intervals using Stack<pair<int,int>>

Tags: c++

I am merging overlapping intervals like

> 5 12, 1 8, 14 19, 22 28, 25 27, 27 30

So, use the logic using the pair<int, int> template. But I can't push pair elements into the Stack<pair<int, int>>, because I'm pushing (&int, &int) instead of (int, int). So, what should I do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void mergeOverlappingIntervals(vector<vector<int>> &arr) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> v;
    for(int i=0; i<arr.size(); i++) {
        v.push_back(make_pair(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]));
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    // for(auto x:v) {
    //     cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
    // }
    stack<pair<int, int>> st;
    st.push(v[0].first, v[0].second);
    for(int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) {
        int top = st.top();
        if(v[i].first <= top.second) {
            top.second = max(top.second, v[i].second);
        }
        st.push(v[i].first, v[i].second);
    }
    while(!st.empty()) {
        int top = st.top();
        cout << top.fist << " " << top.second << endl;
        st.pop();
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> arr(n, vector<int>(2, 0));
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        cin >> arr[i][0];
        cin >> arr[i][1];
    }
    mergeOverlappingIntervals(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It should be `st.push({v[i].first,v[i].second});`

Comment: Also, your while loop has error on line containing `st.top()`. Return type is pair and not int.

Comment: Thanks so we need curly braces to insert or I can insert into the stack using make_pair(int, int) function as well

Comment: always read the complete error message. And include it in the question. If you do not understand it others can explain. The error message should tell you exactly whats wrong and have good hints on how to fix. THe issue is not `int&` vs `int`

Comment: btw I don't understand why `make_pair` (and other `make_...`) is so popular. It was needed rather often in the past, but not anymore. You do not need it here, and it adds nothing useful

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm using make_pair() maybe I'm just a newbie and I started c++ so I don't think that it's so popular but I use to implement various ways of doing same code and it has least worry to me whether it's old or new style of code. Just for the sake of knowledge

Comment: maybe you picked it up from an outdated tutorial. Just do not use it. You will notice when you do need it. Not in this code

Comment: `v.push_back(make_pair(arr[i][0],arr[i][1]));` can be `v.push_back({arr[i][0],arr[i][1]});` and inserting in the stack isn't any different

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say. You got 2 votes, thats almost nothing. And yes one vote is mine, because I asked you to include the complete compiler error message, and you ignored it.  Do you not think it would be good if you told us about the compiler error when your question is about the compiler error? Whats the point of writing all this but then not include the most important piece of information?

Comment: also you should read documentation before posting a question. Look here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push. You could have read that, you could have read the error message, you would have noticed that there is no overload with 2 parameters.

Comment: Yeah I generally write everything about my doubt which included error message too in the past and in that time, others in the community says that I need to debug my code by myself so I stopped writing error messages now.

Comment: If there's exists documentation and internet then what's the purpose of stack overflow, genuinely asking

Comment: reading documentation does not answer all questions. It would have certainly helped with this one. I never said that you should not ask this quesiton but instead read documentation. I only suggested to read documentation before posting the question. Its a way to reduce downvotes.

Comment: I do read documentation from cplusplus, cppreference and geeksforgeeks and even stackoverflow similar questions before writing any questions in here but sometimes you read so many things because of one simple error message that you overlooked, in that scenario I have no choice to ask in here.

Comment: and people in here not like to debug code, if I write error messages too that's what I have experienced. They feel disrespectful and they have other important stuff to discuss like some concepts or some unresolved mystery about coding stuff.

Comment: your motivation to not post the error message is based on a misunderstanding. And "'t push pair elements into the Stack<pair<int,int>> because what I'm pushing is (&int, &int) instead of (int, int). " is a misinterpretation of the error message. To clear it up, the error message is needed.

Comment: Would you kindly recommend me one light weighted IDE for compiling c++ codes, I am using vs code and devc++

Comment: the console is my favourite IDE :)

Comment: then you might write code in editor like sublime text or atom

Comment: Any editor you use to write code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have misunderstood the error message. As you did not include it, I cannot explain it to you.

When I try to compile I get following error message:

```
<source>: In function 'void mergeOverlappingIntervals(std::vector<std::vector<int> >&)':
<source>:16:12: error: no matching function for call to 'std::stack<std::pair<int, int> >::push(int&, int&)'
   16 |     st.push(v[0].first,v[0].second);
      |     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/stack:61,
                 from <source>:4:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/12.2.0/bits/stl_stack.h:260:7: note: candidate: 'void std::stack<_Tp, _Sequence>::push(const value_type&) [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>; _Sequence = std::deque<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >; value_type = std::pair<int, int>]'
  260 |       push(const value_type& __x)
      |       ^~~~

[...]
```

And this is because `std::stack< std::pair<int,int> >::push` has a single parameter, not two. You can find documentation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push

You could use `std::make_pair` as you did when pushing to the vector. Actually pushing to the vector is analogous to pushing to the stack. Though you do not need `std::make_pair` in either case. Just add a pair of `{}` to construct the pair:

```
st.push({v[i].first,v[i].second});
```

Alternatively you can use [`emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/emplace). It does take parameters that are then forwarded to the elements constructor.